# Is it possible to update a jailbroken iOS 7 to a version Apple has stopped signing?

Tags: ios, jailbreak

My iPad is running 7.0.2 and is jailbroken. It looks like Apple is not signing the 7.1.2 any longer.

Is there a way to upgrade iOS to 7.1.2 without letting iTunes contact its home (i.e. Apple's servers)?

Comment: No. You cannot install a version of iOS that Apple is no longer signing.

Comment: Apple is still signing 7.1.2 for the iPhone 4 & equivalent hardware, that can't use iOS 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. It's impossible to upgrade iOS firmware without connecting to the Apple servers.

Currently, there is a jailbreak for iOS 8.1 using [Pangu](https://en.pangu.io/) which is being signed at the moment. iOS 8.1.1 update which is due in a few weeks will patch the jailbreak. It could be the right moment to upgrade your iOS version and re-jailbreak it.  [@saurik confirmed](https://twitter.com/saurik/status/530454505994076161) that the current iOS 8 jailbreak is stable.